# Cons element to list vs cons list to element in Scheme

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, cons

What's the difference between using cons to combine an element to a list and using cons to combine a list to an element in scheme?

Furthermore, how exactly does cons work? Does it add element to the end of the list or the beginning?

Thanks!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez's answer explains this pretty well.  It's helpful to realize that in the Lisp family of languages it's not quite right to think of `cons` as a _list_ operation.  Lisp languages typically have _cons cells_ as genuine datatypes and then implement lists as _intensional datatypes_.  The things that we call lists are lists _by convention_.  I mentioned this in [an earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19126410/1281433) while describing how we can often cons cells to _implement_ lists, but how we can also cons cells to implement other structures, such as trees.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Page Not found.

Comment: @hanQiu I guess that question got deleted.  But there's a section in SO documentation now that covers the same idea:  [lists as a convention](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/2622/cons-cells-and-lists/8700/lists-as-a-convention#t=201608091045099806348)

Comment: That documentation _also_ got deleted :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The primitive `cons` simply sticks together two things, the fact that some of those things are considered lists is incidental. For instance, this works and creates a *pair* (also known as a *cons cell*):

```
(cons 1 2)
=> '(1 . 2)     ; a pair
```

Now, if the second argument to `cons` happens to be a list, then the result will be a new list, and the first argument to `cons` will be added at the head of the old list. In other words: to create a list you need a list, even if it's empty:

```
(cons 1 '(2 3))
=> '(1 2 3)     ; a list

(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))
=> '(1 2)       ; a list

(cons 1 '())
=> '(1)         ; a list
```

But if the second argument to `cons` is *not* a list, then the result will be just a pair, or an *improper list*, meaning that it doesn't end in `'()` as it should to be considered a list:

```
(cons '(1 2) 3)
=> '((1 2) . 3) ; a pair, not a list

(cons 1 (cons 2 3))
=> '(1 2 . 3)   ; an improper list
```

Just to clarify, you can't use `cons` to add elements at the end of a list. The usual way to build a list is going from right-to-left, adding elements in reverse at the head position - say you want to build the list `'(1 2 3)`, then you have to  `cons` the elements in the order `3 2 1`:

```
(cons 3 '())                   ; list is '(3)
(cons 2 (cons 3 '()))          ; list is '(2 3)
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) ; list is '(1 2 3)
```

For those rare occasions where you need to add one element at the end (and believe me, doing so generally means that you're thinking the algorithm wrong) you can use `append`, which receives *two lists* as arguments:

```
(append '(1 2 3) '(4))
=> '(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: When I try (append '() a), I am getting simply 'a.  Can you please explain why so?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29)

Comment: I asked you after looking into docs.  Manual says, v any/c can be added to list.  But it is not telling this peculiar behavior.  What will happen if I append an atom to an empty list.  My understanding is that we should get a list with one element (just appended).

Comment: The relevant part is: "The last argument need not be a list, in which case the result is an “improper list.”". With an empty list as the first argument, it just returns the second argument. In general: the last argument is returned as-is and becomes the last element in the returned list; it can be of any type. All the other arguments must be lists and if they're empty they're ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Sorry to trouble you without properly reading documentation.