# Can someone explain the difference between Cons and Append in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I read both of them and they seem to both construct a single list, what's their difference?

Comment: Look at (cons '(a b) '(c d)) versus (append '(a b) '(c d)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cons element to list vs cons list to element in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213072/cons-element-to-list-vs-cons-list-to-element-in-scheme)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cons` is the constructor for all pairs.

A proper list is `()` (the empty list, aka `nil`) or a pair where the `cdr` is a proper list. Any chain of pairs where the last one has `()` as it's `cdr` is a proper list (in addition to the empty list itself).

A dotted list is a pair that does not have a proper list as it's `cdr`. Thus a chain of pairs where the last `cdr` is not `()` matches this.

```scm
;; dotted lists
(cons 1 2)          ; ==> (1 . 2) 
(cons 1 (cons 2 3)) ; ==> (1 2 . 3) or (1 . (2 . 3))

;; proper lists
(cons 1 '())          ; ==> (1) or (1 . ())
(cons 1 (cons 2 '())) ; ==> (1 2) or (1 . (2 . ()))
```

`append` is a procedure that uses `cons` to make a list with all the elements of the argument lists left to right. A common implementation of `append` for just two lists would be:

```scm
(define (append lst tail)
  (if (null? lst)
      tail
      (cons (car lst)
            (append (cdr lst)
                    tail))))
```

`append` will fail if one of the arguments except the last is not a proper list. Tail and can be any value:

```scm
(append '(1 2 3) '(4 5))       ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5) or (1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . ())))))
(append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 . 6))   ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 . 6) or (1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . 6)))))
(append '(1 2 3) #f)           ; ==> (1 2 3 . #f) or (1 . (2 . (3 . #f)))
(append '(1 2 . 3) '(4 5 . 6)) ; ==> error `car` of number not allowed
```

Comment: Also, cons is generally more efficient as it does not have to go through the whole list.
In terms of big O notation, cons usages are generally O(1) while append is O(n) where n is the length of the list you are dealing with.
While (append (list first_elem) existing_list) technically has the same big O with (cons first_elem existing_list), the latter is more concise and faster.