# Using cons/car vs append to create lists in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to make a list of squares. I can do it with following code:

```
(define (makelistsq n)
  (define outlist '())
  (for ((i n))
    (set! outlist (append outlist (list (* i i))))
    )
  outlist
  )

(makelistsq 5)
```

Output:

```
'(0 1 4 9 16)
```

However, I have seen that often cons and car keywords are used to create and add to lists. Does that method has any advantage over appending as above? So, is following better or same as above:

```
(define (makelistsq2 n)
  (define outlist '())
  (for ((i n))
    (set! outlist (cons (* i i) outlist))
    )
  (reverse outlist)
  )
```

Thanks for your answers/comments.

Edit: on this page [Cons element to list vs cons list to element in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213072/cons-element-to-list-vs-cons-list-to-element-in-scheme) it is mentioned that all use of append is wrong:

> For those rare occasions where you need to add one element at the end
>   (and believe me, doing so generally means that you're thinking the
>   algorithm wrong) you can use append

Comment: I see that you're struggling to get the hang of Scheme. Please grab a book (SICP, How to Design Programs, The Little Schemer) and read, read until you grasp the way to write code in Scheme. So far, you're trying to write procedures as you would in an imperative programming language, and that's definitely not thew way to go when learning a Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't repeat my own answer :P . Yes, using `append` is generally the wrong way to build an output list. But neither of your implementations seem right - most of the time, you have to forget about `set!` and loops.

Recursion is the way to go, and using `cons` and (if necessary) `reverse` at the end is the preferred way to build a list. In fact, the function in the question can be expressed more succinctly using built-in procedures, and this is the recommended way when writing functional-style code:

```
(define (makelistsq2 n)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x x))
       (range n)))
```

For the sake of completeness, let's see how we would write the procedure from scratch, using `cons` for building the output - for those rare occasions when there isn't a built-in procedure that does what you need. This generates a recursive process, notice that here we go from zero to `n-1`:

```
(define (makelistsq2 n)
  (define (helper i)
    (if (= i n)
        '()
        (cons (* i i)
              (helper (add1 i)))))
  (helper 0))
```

The above solution is fine, and works perfectly for small lists. If (and only if) the output list is huge, you might want to build it using tail recursion; this is more efficient as it doesn't require additional memory for the iteration - we'll use a named `let`, and notice that this generates an iterative process, going from `n-1` to zero:

```
(define (makelistsq2 n)
  (let loop ((i (sub1 n)) (acc '()))
    (if (negative? i)
        acc
        (loop (sub1 i) (cons (* i i) acc)))))
```

No matter which implementation you pick, the result is now as expected:

```
(makelistsq2 5)
=> '(0 1 4 9 16)
```

Comment: How do you code if only an integer is being sent to indicate upper level of squares needed (starting from 0). Hence, I need to call the function as (makelistsq3 5) to get '(0 1 4 9 16).

Comment: @rnso there you go, the solution in three different styles

Comment: Great. You could have left previous codes also for everyone to benefit.

Comment: @rnso but I had misunderstood the question :( . Anyway, there are plenty of examples of code like that in SO, some written by me :)

Answer (score 2):

`cons` is the constructor for a pair. A list isn't anything else than a chain of `cons` that is terminated by the empty list `()`.

`append` is a function that uses `cons` in the implementation. Here is the implementation for a two argument append:

```scm
(define (append lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) 
            (append (cdr lst1) lst2))))
```

In plain english it makes an new pair for every pair of `lst1` and then attach the lst2. It's not very efficient so in your first example to produce that 5 element list it has to have made a 4, 3, and 2 element list in addition to the one element list you explicitly made for each step.

When working with lists it iterates in order from first to last, but the creation of a list happens from end to beginning. Often it's not possible to do something in reverse and thus need to reverse the result in the end, but in your case it's easy to count down instead of up.

```scm
(define (make-square-list end)
  (let loop ((n (sub1 end)) (acc '()))
    (if (< n 0)
        acc
        (loop (sub1 n) 
              (cons (* n n) acc)))))
```

With higher order functions you can eliminate the boilerplate but `#!racket` has an alternative that makes even shorter code called `for/list`.

```scm
(define (make-square-list end)
  (for/list ((n (range end)))
    (* n n)))
```

`for/list` is basically the same as `map` but as a special form.

Answer (score 0):

my version:

```
#lang racket

(define (make-square-list n)
  (let loop ([count 1]
             [result_list '()])
    (if (<= count n)
        (loop (add1 count) (cons (* count count) result_list))
        (reverse result_list))))

(make-squqre-list 10)
```

(1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)

Comment: Is "define" better or "let" for inner function? (See "define (helper.." function in an answer above, which is very similar to your fn).

Comment: I prefer to use let to define a inner function.