# Scheme - Inserting a number in a List

Tags: scheme

I have this code :

```
(define (Insert value list)
  (if (null? list) (list value))
  (if (< value (car list)) (list (Insert (value list))))
  (Insert (cdr list) list))
```

I want this code to take a list (assuming it's in low to increasing order of integers) and insert a number in the correct place. This code does not work but I don't know why. Anyone know?

Comment: There's a fundamental error in here, in the way you're building the output list. Use `cons` for that, refer to your text book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors. First, let's see how you can fix your implementation:

```
(define (insert value lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)          ; if the list is empty
         (list value))        ; then return a single-element list
        ((<= value (car lst)) ; if current element >= value
         (cons value lst))    ; insert value in current position
        (else                 ; otherwise keep building the list
         (cons (car lst)      ; by adding current element
               (insert value (cdr lst)))))) ; and advancing recursion
```

Now, let's see what went wrong with your code:

- You must not name a parameter `list`, that clashes with the built-in procedure of the same name - one you're actually using! it's clear that they'll conflict
- The conditionals are incorrectly structured, if you have multiple conditions use a `cond` expression. Notice that the values of the first two `if`s are discarded, because they're not nested (inside a procedure, only the value of the *last* expression is returned). Some Scheme interpreters will even raise an error when you write `if`s without the corresponding `else` part
- In the second condition, you must stop the recursion by `cons`ing the `value` with the rest of the list. It's better to stop as soon as possible, when element >= value, in case there are repeated elements
- In the last condition, you're passing the parameters in the wrong order, and forgot about the `value`
- Also in the last condition, you forgot to `cons` the current element

Comment: Is using cond and else necessary?

Comment: @A.L no, alternatively you can nest `if`s. It's ugly, but works. What you _have to_ ensure is that the conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: What about using cons? I only have experience with using append. Would append work in this case? Or is cons necessary

Comment: `cons` is the most fundamental operation for building new data in Scheme, you should get acquainted with it as soon as possible. Always prefer `cons` over `append`, for efficiency reasons. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19213072/201359).

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code. First, in Scheme it is more natural to include else clauses for `if`s. Also, you had wrong the last `if`. Here is a version of your code with minor modifications:

```
(define (Insert value lst)
  (if (null? lst) (list value)
      (if (< value (car lst))
          (cons value lst)
          (cons (car lst) (Insert value (cdr lst))))))
```

Note that you have to provide actions for when the value is less than the head of the list and when it is not, and you have to construct the returning value using `cons`.