# Racket simple procedure for converting number from base 10 to base 4

Tags: recursion, numbers, racket, procedure

Im having some problems with racket. The assignment wants me to write a procedure that converts any number from base 10 to base 4, the solution should be written in a list. for example (convert-to-base-four 12) -> (list 3 0)
Now i have written a procedure but it inserts each number in an individual list.
heres my code.

```
(define (convert-to-base-four number)
  (cond
    [(<= number 3) (cons number empty)] 
    [(> number 3)  (reverse (list (remainder number 4)
                    (convert-to-base-four (floor (/ number 4)))))]))
```

Does anyone know what to do?
Many thanks

Comment: You're using `list` when you should be using `cons`. Also the digits are going to be jumbled together in the wrong order because of the multiple `reverse` calls on different recursive steps.

Comment: the problem is that if I combined     list and    reverse it gets screwed up. Is this a paranthesis problem?

Comment: No, it's not a paren problem. Your tree is fine. It's mostly a `list` vs. `cons` problem. Then once that's solved you have to figure out whether it should use reverse this way or not.

Comment: in other words when i use "list" I dont need the reverse but the numbers are put individually in lists for example (list (list 3) 0)

Comment: Yes I know. But think about the signature of this function. I'm guessing it should return a list of digits. Now think about the signature of `list`. Given an X and an X, it returns a list of X. But you don't have an X and an X, you have a digit and a list of digits, and you want it to return a list of digits. You're violating the signature of `list`. It's the wrong thing to use here.

Comment: @stuck_in_racket, please see my answer – [`append` is usually the wrong solution in racket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213794/633183) – only use it when necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlexKnauth's comment is the one you need to be following – you must define and adhere to a strict [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (input) and [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) (output) for your function

```
;; from your code
(list Y
      (convert-to-base-four X))
```

It doesn't matter what `Y` and `X` are here: if `convert-to-base-four` returns a list of some value and a recursive call to `convert-to-base-four` – which returns a *list* – you're going to end up with a list of lists!

One solution, as another points out, is to use `append` – but [beware, it's a trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213794/633183)

```
(define (base4 n)
  (if (< n 4)
      (list n)
      (append (base4 (floor (/ n 4)))
              (list (remainder n 4)))))

(displayln (base4 12))     ; (3 0)
(displayln (base4 13))     ; (3 1)
(displayln (base4 14))     ; (3 2)
(displayln (base4 15))     ; (3 3)
(displayln (base4 16))     ; (1 0 0)
(displayln (base4 123456)) ; (1 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 0)
```

A better solution would avoid the costly use of `append` – here we do that using a [named let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) `loop` with two loop state variables `m` and `acc`

```
(define (base4 n)
  (let loop ((m n) (acc empty))
    (if (< m 4)
        (cons m acc)
        (loop (floor (/ m 4))
              (cons (remainder m 4) acc)))))

(displayln (base4 12))     ; (3 0)
(displayln (base4 13))     ; (3 1)
(displayln (base4 14))     ; (3 2)
(displayln (base4 15))     ; (3 3)
(displayln (base4 16))     ; (1 0 0)
(displayln (base4 123456)) ; (1 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 0)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use append on your list :)

Have fun with homework ;)

Comment: This is not an answer! Please read this before contributing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer